# If not chosen all the data in the train partition, is it still k-fold cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, validation

I have a dataset of 900 images, distributed across 6 classes, with 150 images per class. To develop a classifier and assess its performance, I will utilize k-fold cross-validation. In this case, I will employ 3-fold cross-validation.

For each fold, I will allocate 70% of the data for training purposes, leaving the remaining 30% for testing. Consequently, within the training partition, there will be 105 images per class. However, during the training phase, I will only select 20 images per class to train the model. When evaluating the model, I will assess its performance on the entire test partition.

To report the overall performance of the model, I will calculate the average test accuracy across the 3 folds and present this averaged accuracy as the final performance metric.

Despite utilizing a subset of the training partition, can this approach still be referred to as "3-fold cross validation"?

Comment: It is certainly not what people would intuitively expect from "3-fold cross-validation".  They would expect the training set to be split into three subsets of roughly equal size A,B,C. Then train on all of A and B comparing that model to C,  train on all of B and C comparing that model to A, and train on all of C and A comparing that model to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $k$-fold cross-validation there are no "train" and "test" buckets. You put all the data into one bucket, split it into $k$ "folds" and on each iteration you train on $k-1$ folds and test on the remaining one.

That said, there are scenarios where you may want to combine it with classical cross-validation, i.e. do $k$-fold cross-validation on the training data, and then test the final model on the test set. This may be needed to avoid overfitting when you used $k$-fold cross-validation for model selection or picking the best hyperparameters.